# How do you move the Unity Dash with a dual monitor setup?

Tags: 11.04, unity, unity-dash, taskbar

I'm using 2 monitors with Ubuntu 11.04 and can't for the life of me figure out how to move the Unity Dash/Taskbar/whatever to where I want it (the far left side of the left monitor).  No matter what I do it remains on the left side of the right hand monitor.  Has anyone else figured out a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Unity launcher only appears on the primary monitor.  You can adjust the monitors in the Monitors application (available from the Dash) to reconfigure your monitors accordingly.

Comment: I'm actually seeing it on the secondary monitor.  Anyway, this problem seemed to fix itself randomly.  Appears to be a bug in Unity.  Still comes up from time to time but again, usually fixes itself eventually somehow and pops up again on the primary monitor  :/

Comment: I'm not seeing how to mark a monitor as primary in the monitors application. Could you give more details?

Answer (score 1):

This can be set by adding the line to xorg.conf. Take attention to select desired monitor's section.

```
Section "Monitor"
...
    Option    "Primary" "true"
EndSection
```

I can confirm this worked for me with ATI Radeon card + manufacturer's driver: Catalyst 11.9 (Ubuntu 11.04).
Maybe also applicable under different configs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem needed to move DASH to left monitor.
Opened the display app, and just disabled the right monitor, and re-enabled it.

Was enough to make dash jump to left screen.